# Django 'time__contains' is not working in particular case

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to compare time pasted to form with time saved in DB for deleting this record. I don't understand why it's not working when in DB is stored `8:15:00` and the user pasted `08:15`. The field in DB is `TimeField` and for comparing I'm using `.filter(time__contains=t)` where `t` is string pasted from form. Only difference is in zero before 8. When in DB is it stored like `08:15:00`, all is working.

```py
class WateringSchedule(models.Model):
    time = models.TimeField()

t = '08:15'

print(WateringSchedule.objects.filter(time__contains=t).count())
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `time='8:15'`?

Comment: No, because I have `time='08:15'` from form and I tested it ... and not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only seen [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#contains) used with `CharField`. There is no reason to use it here. Just use the field name:

```
print(WateringSchedule.objects.filter(time=t).count())
```

Here I assume Django will parse the input string into a `datetime.time` object. You may need to use `strptime()` to do so manually.

Alternatively, you can use [`hour`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#hour) and [`minute`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#minute).

Comment: with time__time i get: **django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'time' for TimeField or join on the field not permitted.**

Comment: with **__hour** and **__minute** is all working. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should try `icontains` instead of `contains`.

Comment: `icontains` just does case-insensitive comparison. Since the input string contains no alphabetic characters, the only effect `icontains` will have is to make the query slower.